# Remove the commented part and print it?

Tags: php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
     <meta name='Generator' content='Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)'>
     <style><!--
       /* Font Definitions */
       @font-face
        { font-family:'Cambria Math';
          panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
       @font-face
         { font-family:Calibri;
           panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
       @font-face
         { font-family:Tahoma;
           panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
        /* Style Definitions */
       p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
       {margin:0cm;
        margin-bottom:.0001pt;
        font-size:12.0pt;
        font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';}
       a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
        {mso-style-priority:99;
         color:blue;
         text-decoration:underline;}
       a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
        {mso-style-priority:99;
         color:purple;
         text-decoration:underline;}
        p
         {mso-style-priority:99;
          mso-margin-top-alt:auto;
          margin-right:0cm;
          mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;
          margin-left:0cm;
          font-size:12.0pt;
          font-family:'Times New Roman','serif';}
        span.EmailStyle19
          {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
           font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';
           color:#1F497D;}
       .MsoChpDefault
          {mso-style-type:export-only;
           font-size:10.0pt;}
       @page WordSection1
         {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
          margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}
       div.WordSection1
         {page:WordSection1;}
        -->
     </style>
   </head>
  </html>
```

This the html content I get when i read the mail through imap function I want to remove the style tag and the content inside the style tag and then print/echo  it in php. I have i have used preg_match but it does not work

```
preg_replace("/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s", "", $subject[$i])
```

The $subject[$i] is the content in which I have the above html code

Comment: if you remove the style from the above there will be nothing left - where is the body? Rather than `preg_replace` use a `DOMDocument` and remove the `style` that way possibly

Comment: There is conent in the body but I don't want to put it so I removed the body code from the question

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

`<style[\S\s]*?<\/style>` ([Example](http://regexr.com/3cs0t))

Comment: This does not work with me when I print_r($subject[$i]) . get the text in between the style tags . I want to remove the text also . In simple word complete remove the <style> tag and the content inside it.

Comment: Are you actually using `$subject[$i] = preg_replace('/<style[\S\s]*?<\/style>/s', '', $subject[$i]);`? Because preg_replace returns the result and doesn't actually set the variable you're executing the regular expression on.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same thing as you mention in your comment above

Comment: Is [this](https://3v4l.org/ICHmJ) not the intended output? **Edit:** Are you wanting to echo the HTML or the contents of the `style` tags?

Comment: No , Don't want to echo the contents of the style tag

Comment: Yes want the same thing

Comment: But I'm using the line of code in the comment above with the HTML you provided, so the problem would have be something else in your code wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**something like this will help you**

```
$txt=
    ' <html>
     <head>
         <title></title>
         <style>
         body{
            background:#000;
         }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>
    hello world
     </body>
     </html>';

    $a= preg_replace('/(<(style)\b[^>]*>).*?(<\/\2>)/is', "", $txt);
    print_r($a);exit;
```

Comment: it is not removing the style tag.

Comment: it will remove everything inside style tag

Comment: If you want to remove also tags, replacement string in the above code would be empty, so just "".

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** have to use regular expression with HTML, you have to use a parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors( True );
$dom->loadHTML( $subject[$i] );

$styles = $dom->getElementsbyTagName( 'style' );
$styles->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild( $styles->item(0) );
```

By this way you will remove **first** `<style>` node (with its contents).

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read **[why you can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262)**

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to actually removing the style tags and content, again - using DOMDocument, you can simply capture and work with the contents of the document body.

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $subject[ $i ] );
$body=$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $body;
```